# "free -g" and top reporting wildly different memory usage on MySQL server

Tags: mysql, ram, memory-usage, top, free

I am aware of buffers, cache, swap, etc. but can anyone explain this one to me?

First, Here's a TOP output **sorted by memory usage**. Note that MySQL is using 39.4% of the RAM in the system.  Every other process is using so little it reports as zero:

```
Tasks: 728 total,   2 running, 726 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.8 us,  1.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 97.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem : 225344.3 total,   4238.5 free, 217754.1 used,   3351.8 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   8192.0 total,   8176.0 free,     16.0 used.   5988.2 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                
2229271 mysql     20   0   98.9g  86.8g  39456 S  14.9  39.4 623:34.91 mysqld                                                                                                                                                                                 
  45955 grafana+  20   0 4302196  74996  26664 S   2.6   0.0 194:44.43 grafana-agent                                                                                                                                                                          
  45353 root      20   0 3165840  48080  20172 S   0.0   0.0   1:06.33 snapd                                                                                                                                                                                  
    834 root      19  -1  117880  45432  43988 S   0.0   0.0   0:04.42 systemd-journal                                                                                                                                                                        
  45494 root      20   0  111680  36748  32476 S   0.3   0.0   0:05.86 sssd_nss                                                                                                                                                                               
  45490 root      20   0  142632  35488  22776 S   0.0   0.0   0:13.36 sssd_be                                                                                                                                                                                
  45495 root      20   0   86644  23020  19040 S   0.0   0.0   0:03.42 sssd_sudo
```

etc...

Next look at my free -g report:

```
# free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            220         212           4           0           3           5
Swap:             7           0           7
```

If MySQL is only using 39.4% of the 220 GB (86.68 GB,) and cache is taking 3 GB, where's the other 130GB going?  If I restart the MySQL service the total system memory in use will drop to about 12 GB then slowly climbs and climbs.  Usually MySQL will report as using 90% of the RAM but this time when I looked I saw the reports you see above.

Comment: What are values of innodb_redo_log_capacity and innodb_log_buffer_size variables?